# How to make Editable Table Values in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table, http-post

I have my code below

```
<form action="POST">
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['item_Id']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['item_Name']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['itemPicture']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['market_Value']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['bptf_Value']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['opskins_Value']?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input name="sell" placeholder="<?PHP echo "$".$Sell_Price?>" value="<?PHP echo $Sell_Price?>"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input name="keys" placeholder="<?PHP echo $Keys_Price."K"?>" value="<?PHP echo $Keys_Price?>"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input name="refs" placeholder="<?PHP echo $Refs_Price."R"?>" value="<?PHP echo $Refs_Price?>"></td>
</form>
```

it is in a table the input name sell works on saving to SQL with my PHP backend code and not sure why the name keys and name refs don't work; I mean it does have the text boxes but doesn't save it to SQL.

Here is the backend PHP code for it:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  if($s_Bot_Id == $f_Bot_Id ){
    if(isset($_POST['sell'])){
      $content = $_POST['sell'];
      $sql_table = "bot_items_db";
      $sql = "UPDATE $sql_table SET Sell_Price=? WHERE Bot_Id=?";
      $id = $s_Bot_Id;
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $content, $id);
      if ($stmt->execute()){
        return $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close(); 
      }else {
        echo "save not working";
      }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['keys'])){
      $content = $_POST['keys'];
      $sql_table = "bot_items_db";
      $sql = "UPDATE $sql_table SET `Keys_Price` = ? WHERE Bot_Id = ?;";
      $id = $s_Bot_Id;
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $content, $id);
      if ($stmt->execute()){
        return $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close(); 
      }else {
        echo "save not working";
      }
    }
    if(isset($_POST['refs'])){
      $content = $_POST['refs'];
      $sql_table = "bot_items_db";
      $sql = "UPDATE $sql_table SET Refined_Price=? WHERE Bot_Id=?";
      $id = $s_Bot_Id;
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bind_param('ss', $content, $id);
      if ($stmt->execute()){
        return $stmt->affected_rows;
        $stmt->close(); 
      }else {
        echo "save not working";
      }
    }
```

Comment: Where does `$_POST['submit']` come from? I don't see any `<input type="submit" ... />` in Your HTML.

Comment: BTW Your `$stmt->close();` never get called, because there is `return ...` before them.

Comment: Your `<form>` should have `method="post"` if You want to receive the data in `$_POST`.

Comment: I have <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Data" class="btn btn-primary">

Comment: Ok, then how about the `<form method="post" ...>`? Do You have it, too?

Answer (score 0):

You also should add them an id on your html to get the data you can't get the data by the name

```
<form action="POST">
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['item_Id'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['item_Name'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['itemPicture'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['market_Value'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['bptf_Value'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><?PHP echo $_CONFIG['opskins_Value'];?></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input id="sell" name="sell" placeholder="<?PHP echo "$".$Sell_Price;?>" value="<?PHP echo $Sell_Price;?>"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input id="keys" name="keys" placeholder="<?PHP echo $Keys_Price."K";?>" value="<?PHP echo $Keys_Price;?>"></td>
<td class="tg-yw4l" ><input id="refs" name="refs" placeholder="<?PHP echo $Refs_Price."R";?>" value="<?PHP echo $Refs_Price;?>"></td>
</form>
```

Comment: I add in the id tag and it still has the same out put the sell input keeps values but the other 2 do not